# .htaccess and mod_rewrite conditions

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a cache busting engine for my CSS and JS scripts based on PHP and .htaccess. So in PHP i built the following function:

```
function CreateFileFingerprint($RelativePath)
{
    $PathInfo = pathinfo($RelativePath);
    return $PathInfo['dirname'].'/'.$PathInfo['filename'].'.'.filemtime(DATA_BASEPATH.$RelativePath).'.'.$PathInfo['extension'];
}
```

While in my .htaccess I use expiration headers:

```
FileETag None
Header Unset ETag
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A2592000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
<FilesMatch "[^\.php]$">
  Header Append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
```

And a little mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(css|js)$ $1.$3 [L]
```

Then in my PHP page I use the following code:

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.self::CreateFileFingerprint('/styles/style-base.css').'" media="all"/>';
```

Everything works fine, but now I would like to implement an universal PHP ErrorDocument for my site like explained [here](http://kb.siteground.com/article/How_to_create_a_universal_error_page_for_Joomla.html). The problem is that I need to merge my previous mod_rewrite rule with the one suggested in the link:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /errors/error.php [L]
```

Can someone help me please?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . – [S=2]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(css|js)$ $1.$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /errors/error.php [L]
```

remove negation from the conditions and tell it to not to try and match the rewriterules if its a file or directory. Think that should work